# How to restrict an app for Non-Sim Slot devices in Google Play Store?

Tags: android, google-play

I am developing an Android Application and sending SMS or the existence of SIM Slot is the prerequisite. I want to restrict downloading my Application for NON-SIM Slot Devices like Nexus 7 and other Android-powered without SIM-SLOT devices.

is there a way I can achieve this using my AndroidManifest.xml file?

Any Filter in AndroidManifest.xml file?

Answer (score 1):

You should add this in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="true" />
```

> These permissions: CALL_PHONE, CALL_PRIVILEGED, MODIFY_PHONE_STATE,
>   PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS, READ_SMS, RECEIVE_SMS, RECEIVE_MMS,
>   RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH, SEND_SMS, WRITE_APN_SETTINGS, WRITE_SMS
>   implies **android.hardware.telephony** feature requirement.
>
> http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions

Comment: So after defining this, the user can not install the app on Emulator also??

Answer (score 1):

In AndroidManifest.xml, you can add the following line before application tag to make sure the app should be installed only on devices having telephony feature (calls and SMS)

```
<uses-feature
  android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
  android:required="true"/>
```